# Get access control list (IAM) of a resource group in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I am using Node.js to interact with Azure, for example, to create a resource group:

```
const { ResourceManagementClient } = require('azure-arm-resource');

createResourceGroup(location, groupName) {
        const groupParameters = {
            location: location,
        };
        return this.resourceClient.resourceGroups.createOrUpdate(groupName, groupParameters);
    }
```

How can I use these azure-arm modules to retrieve the access control (IAM) list of a resource group?

I mean to this list:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make use of the [**Azure Authorization Modules for Node.js**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/authorization?view=azure-node-latest)

Here is sample code based on Microsoft Docs

Installing Azure Authorization module

```
npm install azure-arm-authorization
```

List all role assignments for a specific resource group

```
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
const authorizationManagement = require('azure-arm-authorization');

const resourceGroup = 'resource-group-name';
const subscriptionId = 'your-subscription-id';

msRestAzure.interactiveLogin().then(credentials => {
 const client = new authorizationManagement(credentials, subscriptionId);
 client.roleAssignments.listForResourceGroup(resourceGroupName).then(result => {
   console.log(result);
 });
});
```

Also on a side note, know that the actual REST API being used for these operations is:

[Role Assignments - List For Resource Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/listforresourcegroup)

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2015-07-01
```

Similar API, which accepts a generic scope (to work with not just resource groups but other resources as well)

[Role Assignments - List For Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/listforscope)

```
GET https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2015-07-01
```

---

**UPDATE** (trying to answer queries from comments)

Using the code above to list all role assignments for a specific resource group (or role assignments - list for resource group REST API).. you will be returned a collection of role assignments, like your comments reflect.

I suppose this is what you need based on the screenshot from your question, as you have Role Assignments tab selected and the list is being shown below in Azure Portal.

Now a role assignment in itself is formed by:

1. A security principal Id (user, group, service principal etc. to whom you're trying to give permissions through a role)
2. Role Definition Id (identifier for the role which you assigning like contributor, owner or a custom RBAC role for that matter)
3. Scope (at which this role is assigned, like at subscription level or at a specific resource group or resource level)

This concept is explained in detail and very well here on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)

For your purpose to make sense of the response UUIDs, you will be able to find the list of all role definitions (to know their ID, Name Description etc. using [Role Definitions List through node SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-arm-authorization/roledefinitions?view=azure-node-latest) or using [Role Definitions - List REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roledefinitions/list)

Principal ID is the ID of user, group or app service principal.

Scope in your case is the resource group that you're trying to query role assignments for.

[image]

Comment: It works but the response is not so useful. The 'type' field is supposed to be either User, Group or App, but it is always ' type:"Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"'. All the other fields (id, name, principalId, roleDefinitionId and scope) contain UUID. for example:

Comment: id:"/subscriptions/de8abfb7-b22b-3c95-8e00-a1a8219e0d98/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/c5f2db94-98c3-3671-8092-fc33d8a474d7"
name:"c5f2db94-98c3-3671-8092-fc33d8a474d7"
principalId:"53a71af7-c241-34e1-b77b-e98151ca6b3f"
roleDefinitionId:"/subscriptions/de8abfb7-b22b-3c95-8e00-a1a8219e0d98/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b23988ac-5180-32a0-ab88-20f7682dd23c"
scope:"/subscriptions/de8abfb7-b22b-3c95-8e00-a1a8219e0d98"
type:"Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"

Comment: Using the code I've mentioned or API, you will be getting back a list of role assignments.. if you look at the screenshot from your question, you will see that is the tab you have selected in portal as well.. Now role assignment in itself has 3 parts.. Security Principal (like user, group etc.), what role they have been assigned (role definition id) and the scope at which they have been assigned this role. It's a little subjective, so I'll try to update my answer and give you more info there..