# azure-graph Users.get(principalID) throws Request_ResourceNotFound

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get the IAM list of a resource group via Node.js. The returned list contains user ids rather than user names, so I am trying to get the user name by user id.

```
const authorizationManagement = require('azure-arm-authorization');
const GraphkManagementClient = require('azure-graph');
const authorizationClient = new authorizationManagement(credentials, subscriptionId);
const graphClient = new GraphkManagementClient(credentials, tenantId);

let iamList = client.roleAssignments.listForResourceGroup(workspaceName);

for (let i in iamList) {
    const user = graphClient.users.get(iamList[i].principalId);
    iamList[i].principalId = user;
}

return iamList;
```

But the line:

```
const user = graphClient.users.get(iamList[i].principalId);
```

throws:

> Request_ResourceNotFound: message:"Resource
>   'b175c95c-e50f-5c46-0b0d-d9f7106d0873' does not exist or one of its
>   queried reference-property objects are not present."

Comment: Are there for sure only users in the list? You can also assign groups and service principals access.

Comment: @juunas there are also Apps and Groups but I don't know what the type of each object is. The value of 'type' is always 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments'

Comment: @juunas I just checked it on an IAM list that contains only  users, and I get the same error.

Comment: @Alon One suggestion would be to not assume that principalid returned is always a user.. you are currently using `users.get` how about trying something more generic like `getObjectsByObjectIds` instead, which will work for all cases like user, group or service principal. Take a look here.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-graph/objects?view=azure-node-latest#getobjectsbyobjectids-getobjectsparameters--object- . If you're getting the error even for IAM list containing only users, it could point to a different issue though.

Comment: @RohitSaigal great, it works! Please write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A role assignment in itself is formed by:

- A security principal Id (user, group, service principal etc. whatever you're  assigning a role to)
- Role Definition Id (identifier for the role which you assigning like contributor, owner or a custom RBAC role for that matter)
- Scope (at which this role is assigned, like at subscription level or at a specific resource group)

This concept is explained in detail and very well here on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)

When getting to a list of Role Assignments like in question here, response object contains `prinicipalId` but not a `principalType` to indicate whether it's a user, group, service principal or MSI. 
So, a safe way to query for this principal is to not assume any particular type, and simply look for an object with that Id.

`getObjectsByObjectIds` method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-graph/objects?view=azure-node-latest#getobjectsbyobjectids-getobjectsparameters--object-)) available in same package `azure-graph` can help with that. Azure AD Graph API being used behind the scene is probably [getObjectsByObjectIds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getObjectsByObjectIds)

One a side node, it's worth mentioning that this question is closely related to [**another SO thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994646/get-access-control-list-iam-of-a-resource-group-in-node-js), so just referencing it here to help with context for anyone reading this in future.