# Authorize a user for azure blob access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager

I am authenticating the users to my web page using the **microsoft login** via **adal-node** library.

***adal-node*** has an **`AuthenticationContext`** from which we can get a ***JWT token*** using **`acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode`**.

So, the users of my active directory app can now successfully login with their Microsoft accounts.

Now, the question is how to get their RBAC roles for a specific *storageaccount/container/blob* using the above received ***JWT Token***? Is that even possible?

Or should I be using a library like ***azure-arm-authorization*** for this purpose? I have set the RBAC roles for each *storageaccount/container/blob* but I am not finding any online documentation on how to get these roles for every logged in user of my app.

Any help would be invaluable.

**TL;DR** How do I authorize azure blobs?

Comment: The data is definitely available through the Azure Resource Management API. I use something like this in an ARM template: `type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/providers/roleAssignments", "apiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview", "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default/', parameters('storageContainerName'), '/Microsoft.Authorization/', guid(resourceGroup().id, 'webAppFilesAccess'))]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my research, if we want to use Azure AD Authentication to acess Azure blob storage, we need to assign Azure RABC role for Azure storage account or container. For more details, please refer to  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad). Besides, we can use Azure CLI to assign role and get role assignment.

For example

```
# assign role
az role assignment create \
    --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" \
    --assignee <email> \
    --scope "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>/blobServices/default/containers/<container>"


# list role assignment of the resource
az role assignment list --scope "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>/blobServices/default/containers/<container>"
```

For further information, please read the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-cli)

---

## Update1

If you want to use nodejs sdk to get the role assignment, please refer to the following code

```
const authorizationManagement = require('azure-arm-authorization');
const msrestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');

const scope = '/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>/blobServices/default/containers/<container>';
const subscriptionId = 'e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68';

msrestAzure.interactiveLogin().then(credentials => {
 const client = new authorizationManagement(credentials, subscriptionId);
 client.roleAssignments.listForScope(scope).then(result => {
    result.forEach(element => { 
       
        client.roleDefinitions.getById(element.roleDefinitionId).then(result => {
             console.log("principal ID: "+ element.principalId+"\nrole name: "+result.roleName)
        });
      }); 
 });
})
```

For more details, please refer to [Get access control list (IAM) of a resource group in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994646/get-access-control-list-iam-of-a-resource-group-in-node-js)

---

## Update2

According to my test, if you want to use `azure-arm-authorization` with `adal-node`. Please refer to the following code

```
const authorizationManagement = require('azure-arm-authorization');
const TokenCredentials = require('ms-rest').TokenCredentials
const adal = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;
const scope = '/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>/blobServices/default/containers/<container>';
const subscriptionId = 'e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68';

// use service principal to get access token with adal-node
/*
  If you do not have a  service principal, you can use the following Azure CLI command(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac) to create it 
    az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role contributor 
    

*/ 
const tenant = 'your-tenant-id';
const authorityUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant;
const clientId = 'your-client-id';
const clientSecret = 'your-client-secret';
const resource = 'https://management.azure.com/';
const context = new adal(authorityUrl);
context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(
     resource,
     clientId,
     clientSecret,
     (err, tokenResponse) => {
          if (err) {
               console.log(`Token generation failed due to ${err}`);
          } else {

               const credentials = new TokenCredentials(tokenResponse.accessToken);

               const client = new authorizationManagement(credentials, subscriptionId);
               client.roleAssignments.listForScope(scope).then(result => {
                    result.forEach(element => {

                         client.roleDefinitions.getById(element.roleDefinitionId).then(result => {
                              console.log("principal ID: " + element.principalId + "\nrole name: " + result.roleName)
                         });
                    });
               });
          }
     }
);
```

[image]

Besides if you want to know how to use passport-azure-ad to get role assignment, you can use passport-azure-ad to get AD access token then call the [Azure rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/listforscope). Regarding how to implement it, you can refer to the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-nodejs-webapi-v2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does help with my question. I need to do this somehow using the arm nodejs API.

Comment: @sp497 Sorry for my delay. Regarding the issue, please refer to my update.

Comment: @sp497 Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: I have not marked this question as accepted becoz i do not use the msrestAzure.interactiveLogin() for my purpose. As I have stated in the question I use adal-node for my authorization and its a completely different workflow.

Comment: @sp497 Could you tell me why you must use ```adal-node```? The ```ms-rest-azure``` is based on ```adal-node```. It just encapsulates the process of requesting a token.Please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/8691046c2ca738552d815f6967f5f54b04840276/runtime/ms-rest-azure/package.json

Comment: Aha. I did not know that ms-rest-azure was based on adal-node. I can try your solution and let you know. Basically I use adal-node with passport-js-custom and do my authentication.

Comment: Also, can 'azure-arm-authorization' be used in conjunction with passport-azure-ad? If so, can u point me to any examples?

Comment: Can I change acquireTokenWithClientCredentials with acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode ? Because I use the Microsoft login page first and post-login it reaches this code.

Comment: @sp497 Yes you can do that

Comment: Great Ill try this and get back to you

Comment: I am getting this error The client 'ff5cba8f-d869-4443-a5dd-5b598d6e991c' with object id 'ff5cba8f-d869-4443-a5dd-5b598d6e991c' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/webprojects/Microsoft.Authorization/read' over scope '/subscriptions/4b1caf79-6e4c-490d-8160-58532983b89f/resourceGroups/Trial/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/testmountstorage/blobServices/default/webprojects/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

Comment: @sp497 According to the error, please assign a RABC role for the client 'ff5cba8f-d869-4443-a5dd-5b598d6e991c'. For more details, please refer to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bc7cfd7a-46d4-4e35-9894-584e5bfb2b60/authorizationfailed-the-client-ltclientidgt-with-object-id-ltobjectidgt-does-not-have?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: Who is the client here ?

Comment: @sp497  The account you use to login Azure AD and get access token is the client

Comment: ok. I have added the permissions using powershell 'az' just like u have mentioned before.

Comment: But it still does not work. Let me show u the output on powershell

Comment: @sp497 Could you please tell me how you set permissions?

Comment: I am going to mark this as accepted for now, as it can be useful for someone else. Meanwhile, we have decided to use blobservice client and facing a similar issue. The question is available at this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59768725/creating-a-blobserviceclient-in-azure-sdk-for-js-with-jwt-accesstoken