# Creating a blobServiceClient in azure-sdk-for-js with JWT accessToken

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager

When migrating from **v2** to **v10** version of a ***azure SDK javascript library***, we have been facing an issue. We need to create a ***`blobServiceClient`*** using the **JWT** ***`accessToken`*** that has been received from ***`acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode`*** function in the **adal-node** library.

The options seem limited to us and the examples are few. ***`SimpleTokenCredential`*** class have been removed from the ***azure-sdk-for-js*** and thus it cannot be instantiated.

Going, through the javascript source code for the ***azure-sdk-for-js*** library I found an option that could be useful for us but I am not sure of it. Its called ***`UserDelegationKeyCredential`***.

Is this the class that is the most suitable for our work/If it is can someone point me to the usage of this class? If this is not the class then which other **KeyCredential** class should be used for our purpose?

Any help would be invaluable.

Comment: I found that you post a similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59772186/using-bearer-tokens-along-with-azure-sdk-for-js. And the issue you have been resolved. I suggest you delete the issue.

Comment: Is this possible to do with UserDelegationKeyCredential ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, the `UserDelegationKeyCredential` class is  only used for generation of user delegation SAS. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/userdelegationkeycredential?view=azure-node-latest)
[image]

Regarding how to create user delegation SAS, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas.

Comment: @sp497 A user delegation SAS is secured with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) credentials and also by the permissions specified for the SAS. In other words,  A SAS secured with Azure AD credentials is called a user delegation SAS. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas